# Publishing symbols with TFS (2018) failed while indexing the source files of .net core 3.1 project

Tags: .net-core, tfs, tfsbuild, .net-core-3.1

running the task "Index Sources & Publish Symbols", using on-premises TFS 2018, with the following settings

```
Path to publish symbols: \\myFileshareServer\symbols
Search pattern: **/*.pdb
Path to symbols folder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

[TFS .NetCore Toolinstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LONPN.png)

[BuildConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjIln.png)

[TFS Symbols step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4koW.png)

I always get the following warning message for every pdb that is generated. (The project is build with .net core 3.1)

> At least one source file for the symbol file xxx.pdb could not be indexed

The pdb files will be copied to the fileshare, but the warning messages, that no file could be indexed is making me mad. On an other project with .net 4.7.2 with the same steps, all is working fine.

I also tried

```
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
```

and

```
<DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
```

Nothing worked, always the same warning message.
What do I have to do to get the files indexed? What could be the reason why all files can not be indexed?

Thanks a lot.

Publish Symbols log. (Sorry, I hope the german output of publish log is ok. Otherwise I need to contact my TFS admin :) )

```
2020-08-07T11:04:30.3983664Z ##[section]Starten: Pfad für Symbolveröffentlichung
2020-08-07T11:04:30.3987884Z ==============================================================================
2020-08-07T11:04:30.3988026Z Task         : Quellen indizieren und Symbole veröffentlichen
2020-08-07T11:04:30.3988318Z Description  : Indizieren Sie Ihren Quellcode, und veröffentlichen Sie Symbole für eine Dateifreigabe oder den Visual Studio Team Services-Symbolserver.
2020-08-07T11:04:30.3988634Z Version      : 2.0.7
2020-08-07T11:04:30.3988709Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-08-07T11:04:30.3989139Z Help         : Unter [Weitere Informationen](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613722) erhalten Sie weitere Informationen zum Verwenden dieser Aufgabe. Visual Studio Team Services-Symbolserver befindet sich in der öffentlichen Vorschau. Lesen Sie [diese Anweisungen](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=846265) zur Verwendung von Symbolserver in VSTS.
2020-08-07T11:04:30.3989566Z ==============================================================================
2020-08-07T11:04:32.0388621Z Es wurden 2 Dateien gefunden.
2020-08-07T11:04:33.6716180Z Mindestens eine Quelldatei für die Symboldatei "D:\Build\1\749\s\SpielProjekt\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpielProjekt.pdb" kann nicht indiziert werden.
2020-08-07T11:04:33.8983354Z ##[command]"D:\Build\1\_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.7\pdbstr.exe" -w -p:"D:\Build\1\749\s\SpielProjekt\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpielProjekt.pdb" -i:"C:\Users\srv_tsfbuild_fdt02\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp19DD.tmp" -s:srcsrv
2020-08-07T11:04:33.9354219Z Mindestens eine Quelldatei für die Symboldatei "D:\Build\1\749\s\SpielProjekt\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpielProjekt.pdb" kann nicht indiziert werden.
2020-08-07T11:04:33.9558971Z ##[command]"D:\Build\1\_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.7\pdbstr.exe" -w -p:"D:\Build\1\749\s\SpielProjekt\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\SpielProjekt.pdb" -i:"C:\Users\srv_tsfbuild_fdt02\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1A1C.tmp" -s:srcsrv
2020-08-07T11:04:34.1041810Z ##[command]"D:\Build\1\_tasks\PublishSymbols_0675668a-7bba-4ccb-901d-5ad6554ca653\2.0.7\symstore.exe" add /f "@C:\Users\srv_tsfbuild_fdt02\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1A6B.tmp" /s "\\wkoe.wk.wknet\file\init_tae_symbols" /t "SpielwieseMarkus" /v "1.0.0.2"
2020-08-07T11:04:34.3481091Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Artefakt zuordnen
2020-08-07T11:04:34.3702107Z Das Artefakt 29552 wurde dem Build 17352 zugeordnet.
2020-08-07T11:04:34.3703184Z ##[section]Async Command End: Artefakt zuordnen
2020-08-07T11:04:34.3703816Z ##[section]Abschließen: Pfad für Symbolveröffentlichung
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot and found the "solution", that the messages of the tfs are false negative.
All pdb files are, which could not be indexed, indexed correctly and I can step into all code, if I add the NuGet package to a project and debug it.

For all who have the same problem: Check if the pdb files are generated. Try to debug into the external code and check the file, which is downloaded. It should have the correct commit ID in the file path.

At least I disabled the warnings if a pdb could not be indexed and just generate the messages as "info" in the build.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

1.You should add script below to the first property group in your project file:

```
<DebugType>full</DebugType>
<DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
```

2.Make sure you're in **Debug** mode.

Then it works well in my machine with TFS2018 update3.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer. I used the script you posted (still had it in my .csproj) and changed my build config to Debug.
But still same error, "At least one source file for the symbol file xxx.pdb could not be indexed"

Comment: Can you show me the tasks/steps in your pipeline, and the details about how you define them? So that I can try to reproduce same issue on my side~

Comment: Hi, i edited the question and added links to screenshots to all 3 build steps I used. I only blackened the name of product/fileshare network server. Do you need some more details?
Thank you

Comment: I'll check that and share the latest news if there's any update:)

Comment: I can't reproduce same issue in azure devops server2019 or azure devops service following your steps, have you ever tried to add nuget publish step in the pipeline?

Comment: Not in the build pipeline, what could change it?
The package is published with nuget publish in our own feed after the build, in a release release step. Curious is, that all is fine with same steps with a .net framework project. But i can't find out why .net core is producing this error/behavior

Comment: Does this issue even occurs in a simple .net core project? Set the debug=true and run the pipeline again, then share the detailed log of publish symbol task in your question so that I can check it directly.

Comment: Hi, I tried with new .net core project with only 1 class and got the same error. The publish log is added to the question. Thank you very much